# Конвертирование java.awt.Color в javafx.scene.paint.Color

Tags: color, javafx, цвета, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно перевести `java.awt.Color` в `javafx.scene.paint.Color`

Вся проблема заключается в том, что в `java.awt.Color` конструктор для цвета определён значениями из обычной RGB-палитры, int от 0 до 255. Тогда как в `javafx.scene.paint.Color` значения R, G и B представлены, как double от 0 до 1.

Естественно, обычному касту не поддается.
Цель перевода цвета - рисование на canvas в javafx.

Comment: @Mad Scientist, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.Color color = new java.awt.Color(10, 100, 200);
        javafx.scene.paint.Color newColor = new javafx.scene.paint.Color(color.getRed() / 255, color.getGreen() / 255, color.getBlue() / 255, 1);
    }
}
```